# Share to Facebook Button android studio

Tags: android, facebook, post

I have an application where I have a share to facebook and twitter button. I was able to manage with the Twitter button, but this code for the facebook share gives me errors and it crashes my apllication. This is the first time I am using the Facebook sdk and I was not able to find relevant explanations in the Facebook DOCS. The button should post to the users wall a text saying something.

```
public void shareToFacebook(View view){
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com")).setRef("eee")
        .build();
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.sharefb);
shareButton.setShareContent(content);
// this part is optional
shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {});
            if(ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class))

            {
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                        .setContentDescription(
                                "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                        .build();

                shareDialog.show(linkContent);
            }
```

This is basically what is in the DOCS, as I have been unable to compile it and then see what part does what with Log.

UPDATE:

Here is the Error Log:
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

is not abstract and does not override abstract method onError(FacebookException) in FacebookCallback

```
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.inc.nicky.tapit.TapAdventure.moveButton(TapAdventure.java:126)
            at com.inc.nicky.tapit.TapAdventure.tapped(TapAdventure.java:136)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can u please add the error log / stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

If You want Share image with caption on facebook may this function can help.

There is two types to share any things on third party libraries.

> (i) Using intent.
>       ==> problem is that when you share using intent on facebook that can't
>           display title with image.
>
> (ii). you must implement third parti libraries into your project.

Now, for this question.

> (1). Simply i create a function for share to facebook. (2).call it on
>   share button onClick event.

**step 1 :**

```
private void sharePhotoToFacebook()
{
   Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.avatar);

   SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(image)
                .setCaption("Nice Place.....")
                .build();

  SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

  ShareApi.share(content,null);
  Toast.makeText(facebook_signin.this,"Facebook Photo Upload Complated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

**step 2:**

```
share.setOnClickListener(   new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                sharePhotoToFacebook();
            }
        });
```

**step 3:**
Login with facebook account and here we can see post which is uploaded.

Comment: I tried using this but it does not recognize setCaption. Which version of FacebookSDK are you using?

Comment: compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

Comment: You can also do this by share dialog

Comment: Now I am getting this weir error: Could not execute method of the activity
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703729/android-studio-facebook-show-content-not-working link to the problem

Answer (score 0):

**It can be possible by using share dialog of facebook sdk.**

**Step 1:** Create object ShareDialog class which is default to facebook sdk 4.+ versions.

```
ShareDialog shareDialog;
```

**Step 2:** In onCreate.

```
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
```

**Step 3:** Create one button in layout and assign it in onCreate.

```
share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
```

**Step 4:** In onClick event of share button

```
 ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_share);
            Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(ivImage);

            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(bmp)
                    .setCaption("This Is Nice Place !!!!!")
                    .build();

            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();
            shareDialog.show(content);



            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                    .setContentDescription(
                            "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                    .build();

            shareDialog.show(content);
```

Comment: setCaption not recognized. Should this be done in a fragment?